# Xcode ios objective c Thread

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, multithreading

I want to make an simple ios app.

I want to click on the button and change the backgroundcolor of buttons in a view.

It already is working, but i want to do it asnyc.

For example.

Buttton1 grey
Wait a second
Button2 grey
Wait
And so on.

This is the base source:

```
int i = 1;
UIView *view = viewButtons;
for(UIButton *btnItem in view.subviews)



    NSString *strValue = [@(i) stringValue];
    btnItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [btnItem setTitle: strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    i++;

    usleep(1000 * 1000);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this async? Any UI changes should ALWAYS be made on the main thread.

Comment: I guess because the current code will block the main UI thread

Comment: There are probably 10 different ways to do timed operations in iOS.  Do a little research.

Comment: (And never, ever use a "sleep" operation unless you *really* know what you're doing.)

Comment: @HotLicks as an academic exercise, can you think of any occasion in iOS programming where a sleep would be appropriate? I'm struggling but possibly I just lack imagination.

Comment: @Tommy - There are probably cases where a short sleep (maybe 100 ms)  is reasonable, to allow some action to occur, or in certain locking scenarios.  But you'd need to know what you were doing.

Comment: @HotLicks oh, yeah, I guess if you had a less-tight-than-usual spin lock, and you either wanted code clarity or discovered `sleep` to be a cheaper way of temporarily blocking. You got my +1 already for italicising 'really'.

Comment: @Tommy - It's not unusual, when a lock is denied, to sleep/spin briefly before retrying.  If the lock is still denied then some sort of long wait mechanism is used.

Comment: @HotLicks but it's relatively unusual to use `sleep` for that. That's why `NSLock` has `lockBeforeDate:` — that stuff is already implemented for you. And you bet Apple knows the best way to talk to its scheduler.

Comment: @Tommy - Yeah, I was speaking generally -- not specific to any iOS scenario.  Generally where the short wait is worthwhile it's built into the standard locking mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). It will allow you to specify an interval and whether you want to repeat the action or not. As Hot Licks mentioned, there are other ways to do it. If you decide to create the thread on your own, e.g. using [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html), remember that UI updates must be always made on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either NSTimer (as previously mentioned) or a dispatch_after() call. If it's a repeating action, use an NSTimer and set it to repeat. If it's a non-repeating action, you could either use an NSTimer set not to repeat, or a dispatch_after() call. Up to you. Definitely do not thread UI code; that has undefined behavior (in other words, it will not work properly).